# Need help diagnosing a 500 error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I built a webapp for a class that uses a weather API to display the local weather on a single page. I've uploaded the app to Heroku, but when I try to view the page, I get a 500 error. I've looked at the logs, but I can't decipher what is going wrong exactly. Can someone please take a look at the logs and point out what's going wrong?

Here is a link to the logs: https://gist.github.com/allredbm/70daea5a4c372c644cac

Comment: can you post what's in line `app/controllers/home_controller.rb:18` ?

Comment: This is what is on line 18: "@location = response["location"]["city"]". I don't know why this won't work for Heroku, since this works without any errors in the rails server.

Comment: That means that response["location"] is blank (nil or empty)

Comment: The problem was that Heroku needed my API key in order to define location. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is as follows:

```
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:18:in `index'
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

On line `18` of your `home_controller` (`index` action), you're referencing a variable with a `[]`. The variable isn't defined.

You need to make sure the variable is defined before trying to reference it.

Comment: The problem was Heroku needed my API key in order to define the variable. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks buddy, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can view the whole backtrace by doing either:

- Set `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` - this is the quickest
- Add New Relic (free), configure it, reproduce the 500, wait 1 minute and go into the errors tab in New Relic - this is the preferred as you don't expose the error to the public