# rails api on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-api

I built an api-only rails app using rails-api. It works great locally. However, when I deploy it to heroku, it produces error saying `We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.`.

I then checked logs with command `heroku logs` in CLI:

```
2016-01-26T22:11:39.472621+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2016-01-26T22:11:39.472645+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.0.0-p648), codename: Autumn Arbor Airbrush
2016-01-26T22:11:39.472647+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2016-01-26T22:11:39.472647+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2016-01-26T22:11:40.839892+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:12329
2016-01-26T22:11:40.840054+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2016-01-26T22:11:40.994291+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-26T22:11:42.865549+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=hereze.herokuapp.com request_id=2823dd98-073a-40b5-9faa-1caed3ed263f fwd="89.166.7.101" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=38ms status=404 bytes=1744
2016-01-26T22:11:50.101468+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/reviews" host=hereze.herokuapp.com request_id=2d0d04a6-90c5-4ae7-84a8-2fd1e6287ea3 fwd="89.166.7.101" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1669
2016-01-26T22:12:41.819043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/reviews" host=hereze.herokuapp.com request_id=854512e4-7a19-4453-9254-2ce09472b5bb fwd="89.166.7.101" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=36ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

But I don't see anything wrong in the logs, can you help me out? Thank you.

Comment: This is not enough information to help you.  We can confirm that the API is returning a 500.  See if there's some way that you can include more information in the error logs, or add an error tracker to your Heroku stack.  A common cause is failure to run heroku run rake db:migrate, try that.

Comment: Check this answer on how to get more info on that 500: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35023278/338536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do Cntrl+F and then search for error. The code you listed does not include any errors.

But if it is working locally but not in Heroku you probably have forgotten to run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate

or

heroku run rake db:seed
```